# Differential equations of a forced coupled spring-pendulum system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, spring, coupled-oscillators

Currently working on a problem and I can really figure out how to write the differential equations for it. Here's the situation:

[image: Image of the system]

So we have a mass $m$ tied to the wall with a spring of constant $k$. The wall itself is oscillating and its position is given by $x_0 \cos(\omega t)$. Tied to the mass is a pendulum of length $L$ and mass $m$. I have to figure out the equation for the amplitude. My guess so far is the following (1 being the spring-mass and 2 being the pendulum):

$$m_1\ddot{x}_1=-k(x_1-x_0\cos(\omega t))+\frac{mg}{L}(x_2-x_1)$$
$$m_2\ddot{x}_2=\frac{-mg}{L}(x_2-x_1)$$

But I'm not entirely sure about them. Since the pendulum is tied to the moving mass, I've considered writing the second one as:

$$m_2(x_2-x_1)''=\frac{-mg}{L}(x_2-x_1)$$

But I'm not sure the logic holds. If that's of any help, I have to prove that the equations for the amplitude are:

$$A_1=\frac{kx_0(g-L\omega^2)}{mL\omega^4-(2mg+kL)\omega^2+kg}$$
$$A_2=\frac{kgx_0}{mL\omega^4-(2mg+kL)\omega^2+kg}$$

**EDIT:**

It seems the first differential equations were right, I managed to obtain the correct amplitudes by substituting the complex solutions $x_1 \rightarrow z_1=A_1e^{i\omega t}$ and $x_2 \rightarrow z_2=A_2e^{i\omega t}$. Leaving this here in case it could help someone.

Comment: I may help to define to what $A_{1}$ and $A_{2}$ refer, i.e., is one for the block and one for the bob on the pendulum?

Comment: Yes, indeed one is for the block and one is for the pendulum. Although after a while I managed to obtain the expressions for $A$ using the first DEs I had written.